# R subset logical

Tags: r, logical-operators, subset

I have a list of data that I want to subset based on two variables (partition, deployment.date). Based on the articles and manuals, I should be able to do it using a single ampersand. What I am seeing however is that each one works on its own but not when combined.

```
> tail(x)
             Composite  Version                    Partition Deployment.Date
6   MaintenanceService 1.4.34.5  SpecialProgram-IneligibleCR      2014-10-01
7   MaintenanceService 1.4.34.5  SpecialProgram-IneligibleCR      2014-10-01
8          Integration    1.6.1            SpecialProgram-PT      2014-10-13
9          Integration    1.6.1            SpecialProgram-PT      2014-10-13
10   UpdateTermChanges    1.9.0                   TermChange      2014-09-28
11 UpdateTermChangesV2 1.13.0.1                   TermChange      2014-09-24


> x[ grep("2014-10", x$Deployment.Date) , ]
                   Composite  Version                    Partition Deployment.Date
1   TermChangeEventProcessor  1.9.1.1                   TermChange      2014-10-31
2 TermChangeIntegrationLayer  1.1.2.1                   TermChange      2014-10-31
3               UpdateOffers    2.5.2                   TermChange      2014-10-10
4               UpdateOffers    2.5.3                   TermChange      2014-10-13
5         MaintenanceService 1.4.34.4  SpecialProgram-IneligibleCR      2014-10-01
6         MaintenanceService 1.4.34.5  SpecialProgram-IneligibleCR      2014-10-01
7         MaintenanceService 1.4.34.5  SpecialProgram-IneligibleCR      2014-10-01
8                Integration    1.6.1            SpecialProgram-PT      2014-10-13
9                Integration    1.6.1            SpecialProgram-PT      2014-10-13


> x[(x$Partition == " TermChange"), ]
                    Composite  Version   Partition Deployment.Date
1    TermChangeEventProcessor  1.9.1.1  TermChange      2014-10-31
2  TermChangeIntegrationLayer  1.1.2.1  TermChange      2014-10-31
3                UpdateOffers    2.5.2  TermChange      2014-10-10
4                UpdateOffers    2.5.3  TermChange      2014-10-13
10          UpdateTermChanges    1.9.0  TermChange      2014-09-28
11        UpdateTermChangesV2 1.13.0.1  TermChange      2014-09-24
```

But when I use them together the result isn't what I expect.

```
> x[( (grep("2014-10", x$Deployment.Date)) & (x$Partition == " TermChange")), ]
                    Composite  Version   Partition Deployment.Date
1    TermChangeEventProcessor  1.9.1.1  TermChange      2014-10-31
2  TermChangeIntegrationLayer  1.1.2.1  TermChange      2014-10-31
3                UpdateOffers    2.5.2  TermChange      2014-10-10
4                UpdateOffers    2.5.3  TermChange      2014-10-13
10          UpdateTermChanges    1.9.0  TermChange      2014-09-28
11        UpdateTermChangesV2 1.13.0.1  TermChange      2014-09-24
Warning message:
In (grep("2014-10", x$Deployment.Date)) & (x$Partition == " TermChange") :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

I have played with the parenthesis groupings as well as using double-ampersands. What am I missing so that I can subset all TermChange entries deployed on 2014-10?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like the `filter` function from the `dplyr` package

```
library(dplyr)
filter(x, grepl("2014-10",Deployment.Date) & Partition==" TermChange"))
```

(tested on local data)

Answer (score 1):

You've mixed index-based subsetting (using integers) and inclusion-exclusion subsetting (using booleans).

```
> x <- 9:12

> grep('1', x)  # indexes
[1] 2 3 4
> x[grep('1', x)]
[1] 10 11 12

> grepl('1', x)  # boolean
[1] FALSE TRUE TRUE TRUE
> x[grepl('1', x)]
[1] 10 11 12

> x<11  # boolean
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
> x[x<11]
[1] 9 10

> which(x<11)  # indexes
[1]  1 2
> x[which(x<11)]
[1] 9 10
```

You can only combine indexes with indexes or combine booleans with booleans.

```
> grepl('1',x) & x<11  # both boolean
[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE

> intersect(grep('1',x), which(x<11))  # both indexes
[1] 2

> grep('1',x) & x<11  # mixed
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
Warning message:
In grep("1", x) & x < 11 :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

Comment: thanks. any tips on how to combine the two without resorting to an external package?